# Splitting a scanner string

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class web_practice {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.next();

        int l = input.indexOf(' ');
        String cmd = input.substring(0, l);
        String end = input.substring(l);

        if (cmd.equals("define"));
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + end));
    }
}
```

I was trying to make a code to find the definition of a word by connecting it to dictionary.com and checking if they say the word "define" as the first word?

The splitting is not working.

Comment: Where you are using split ?

Comment: What means "The splitting is not working"? What is the input?

Comment: Can you put `input` string value?

Comment: btw, `if (condition);` reduces to a noop thanks to the semi-colon (assuming a side-effect free condition). this is one reason it's considered best practice to always use braces with your `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.next();

        int words[] = input.split(' ');

        if (words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("define")) {
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + words[0]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
public class Sol {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        String[] input = new String[2];     
        input = in.readLine().split(" "); 
        int a; 
        int b; 
        a = Integer.parseInt(input[0]); 
        b = Integer.parseInt(input[1]); 

        System.out.println("You input: " + a + " and " + b); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work for you

```
    String[] strArr = input.split(" ") ; 

    if(strArr[0].equals("define"){
    }
```

Comment: How would I then get the rest of the string to add to the end of the url. I tried doing strArr[1], but it said it was out of bounds.

Comment: the code above for sure will get you the first word, the rest do it your way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using `Scanner` which default behavior is to split the `InputStream` by whitespace. Thus when you call `next()`, your `input` string contains the command only, not the whole line. Use `Scanner.nextLine()` method instead.

Also take a note that `String end = input.substring(l);` will add a space into the end string. You probably want to use `String end = input.substring(l+1);`. Here's the fixed `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    int l = input.indexOf(' ');
    if(l >= 0) {
        String cmd = input.substring(0, l);
        String end = input.substring(l+1);

        if (cmd.equals("define"));
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                java.net.URI.create("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + end));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in your code is using `scanner.next();` the `next()` method will read the next token without space for ex for console input `define blabla`  the value of `input` variable would be `define` ie without space so in your case there is no space character so `input.indexOf(' ');` will return `-1` giving exception for `substring()` a quickfix would be change the line `scanner.next();` to `scanner.nextLine();` which would read the whole line rather than token.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.next();;
    String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
    if (inputs[0].equalsIgnoreCase("define")){  java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" ));}
```

Comment: you can use String split () method. it will return you an array of strings. now you can get your string by index.

Comment: To prevent null pointer errors, you should use `"define".equalsIgnoreCase(inputs[0])`—it's considered good practice.